# Pointer Arithmetic in Opencv Using CvMat?

Tags: pointers, opencv, matrix

So I'm trying to access matrix elements via a pointer. Here is my code:

```
    CvMat *Q = cvCreateMat(3,3, CV_32F);
    for(int i = 0; i < Q->rows ; i++){
    float *ptr = (float *)(Q->data.ptr + i * Q->step );
    for(int j = 0; j < Q->cols ; j++){
        *ptr = 0.0;
        if((i ==0)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 1;
        if((i ==0)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 2;
        if((i ==0)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 3;
        if((i ==1)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 4;
        if((i ==1)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 5;
        if((i ==1)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 6;
        if((i ==2)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 7;
        if((i ==2)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 8;
        if((i ==2)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 9;
        //cout << *ptr << endl;
        //system("pause");
    }
}
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,0,0) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,0,1) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,0,2) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,1,0) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,1,1) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,1,2) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,2,0) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,2,1) << endl;
cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q,float,2,2) << endl;
system("pause");
```

I am trying to make the matrix in the for loop as:

[1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9],

but when cout'ing them, I get:

3

-4.31602e+008

-4.31602e+008

6

-4.31602e+008

-4.31602e+008

9

-4.31602e+008

-4.31602e+008

Where is the -4.31602e+008 coming from? What am I not understanding here? I'm a little new to pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the API for [CvMat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvmat) (also you might want to consider using Mat if you can use c++).

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but if you want to access the data using the pointer you are doing it slightly wrong at this point.

```
float *ptr = (float *)(Q->data.ptr + i * Q->step );
```

The step here is the number of bytes in a row (so here it would be 12, 4 bytes per element * 3 elements) the pointer will automatically step the correct number of bytes based on the datatype of the pointer when you do arithmetic with it (Good tutorial [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html)). In order to access it like an array you should do it like this:

```
CvMat *Q = cvCreateMat(3,3, CV_32F);
for(int i = 0; i < Q->rows ; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < Q->cols ; j++){
    float *ptr = (float *)(Q->data.ptr) + i*Q->rows + j; //Index is row major
    if((i ==0)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 1;
    if((i ==0)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 2;
    if((i ==0)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 3;
    if((i ==1)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 4;
    if((i ==1)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 5;
    if((i ==1)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 6;
    if((i ==2)&&(j==0)) *ptr = 7;
    if((i ==2)&&(j==1)) *ptr = 8;
    if((i ==2)&&(j==2)) *ptr = 9;
   }
}
```

A much simpler solution would be to use the CV_MAT_ELEM macro that exists.

```
CvMat *Q = cvCreateMat(3,3, CV_32F);
for(int i = 0; i < Q->rows ; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < Q->cols ; j++){
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*Q, float, i, j) = i*Q->rows + j + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: On the line where you defined *ptr, how is it possible to add the floating pointer (float*)(Q->data.ptr) to the non-pointer i*Q->rows+j? And what does Q->data.ptr point to exactly? The first element of a row?

Comment: The data in CvMat is stored as an array, Q->data.ptr is a pointer to the start of that array.  On that line I am adding ( i*Q->rows+j) to the start of the pointer, this moves the pointer along the array that many spots. Reading up on pointer arithmetic would help you understand: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html

Answer (score 0):

You should increment `ptr` inside your inner `j` loop.